# Mongo to BigQuery Export: Handling Dates

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

I am trying to dump some collections from mongo to bq (big query). The steps I am following are:

1. Export from mongo as json using mongoexport
2. Import the json files into bq. The documents structures are very complicated with multiple levels of nesting and arrays so I am using the autodetect schema option which does a good job of detecting the schema.

The issue I would like to resolve is as follows:

In mongo the date fields are stored as {"lastUpdateTime" : ISODate("2020-11-21T11:40:12.717Z")}.
Mongoexport extracts this as {"lastUpdateTime" : {"$date": "2020-11-21T11:40:12.717Z"}}.
I then replaced the $date with date using sed in a bash script. This results in the following bq schema

| Field Name | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lastUpdateTime | RECORD | NULLABLE |
| lastUpdateTime.date | TIMESTAMP | NULLABLE |

Which is the best way to have the lastUpdateTime as a TIMESTAMP without the unnecessary nesting?

1. Use regex to replace {"lastUpdateTime" : {"$date": "2020-11-21T11:40:12.717Z"}} with {"lastUpdateTime" : "2020-11-21T11:40:12.717Z"}, but I can't think of a regex to do that.
2. Use bq to do the transformations but there are 2 issues.

- the date fields occur inside arrays and in deep nested structures so not sure how complicated this will be with bq
- will have to manually identify all the places where dates exist and write bq transformations

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **jolt transformation library** to transform the extended Mongodb Schema JSON data to Standard JSON schema. The spec defined in the jolt can remove any **unwanted character** such as **_id** and **date**. Check [this link](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) to see how you can define and validate a jolt spec and [this](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) to learn more about the configuration.